# How to loop a google script function but with a different range value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i need some help in writing a google script, and well i'm pretty new to the whole thing. I tried to search for some solution or a way to do this simple script (the ideia seems simple) but maybe because i'm still learning the basics i'm lost.

I have this spreadsheet, i need to make one pivot table for each column in the spreadsheet (starting B1;B75 and ending at FE1;FE75). I made a simple script that do a simple pivot table in a defined range, but here is the real problem, i want the range to be variable (do various pivot tables, when done doing one goes to the next column and does another till it gets to the last column FE1;FE75) so i don't need to repeat all the routine for every column.
Here what i got:

```
  function test92pivottable() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B75').activate();
  var sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B75');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(2);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(2, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(2);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C1:C75').activate();
  sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('C1:C75');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(3, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1:D75').activate();
  sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('D1:D75');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(4);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(4, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(4);  
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E75').activate();
  sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('E1:E75');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(5);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(5, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(5);  
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('F1:F75').activate();
  sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('F1:F75');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(6);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(6, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(6);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Respostas ao formulário 1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G1:G75').activate();
  sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('G1:G75');
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getIndex() + 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setHiddenGridlines(true);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(7);
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(7, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(7);
  };
```

As you can see the soluction i found was to repeat the inicial routine but changing the values of

> spreadsheet.getRange('**C1:C75**').activate();
>
> sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('**C1:C75**');
>
> pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(**3**);
>
> pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(**3**,
> SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
>
> pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(**3**);

but this would make the script huge.

I'm sorry if i'm being unclear. I'm used to look up answers in forums like this but not asking the questions myself!

Thanks

Comment: Please rewrite your code without using the activate method.  And explain what you want to do with the pivot tables.  Images of your spreadsheet may be helpful as well

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: @Cooper Sorry man, it seems i jumped the gun here! Thanks for the links i will edit my question and be more clear. If its not a bother can you tell me what you meant when you said "activate method" ? I really thought that i could just copy and paste from google script the code and it would be alright. Sorry again and thanks for the information.

Comment: People  who learn how to write script by creating macros first tend to over use the activate method as show here from you example `spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B75').activate();`  Where as people who have learned javascript first and then read the google apps script documentation to learn apps script hardly ever use the .activate() method.

Answer (score 0):

This is just sort of a general answer to your current question of how to iterate through different sheets and ranges.

```
function loopthroughfunctionwithdifferentrangevalues() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rA=['A1:A75','B1:B75','C1:C75'];
  const sA=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  sA.forEach((sh,s)=>{
    let sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sh);
    rA.forEach((rg,r)=>{
      let rg=sheet.getRange(rg);
      let vals=rg.getValues();
        //Put code in here.
    })
  });
}
```

You can use something like this to iterate through all the sheets in a spreadsheet except for a selected subset and some ranges in each sheet.

```
function loopthroughfunctionwithdifferentrangesandsheetsandexcludesomesheets() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rA=['A1:A75','B1:B75','C1:C75'];
  const xA=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];//exclude these sheets
  const shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach((sh,s)=>{
    if(xA.indexOf(sh)==-1) {
      let sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sh);
      rA.forEach((rg,r)=>{
        let rg=sheet.getRange(rg);
        let vals=rg.getValues();
        //Put code in here.
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper implies you can simplify your code by extracting the instructions that will be repeated "for each" range "of each" sheet that you want to convert into a pivot table by creating [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that hold such sheets and ranges and looping through the desired instructions (create pivot table) using a [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

Follow the links provided for the official documentation on JavaScript Arrays.